# How to group a List<Dictionary<string,string>> based on particular key and get the max value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, group-by

I have the following `List<Dictionary<string,string>>`:

```cs
List<Dictionary<string,string>> data = new List<Dictionary<string,string>> 
{
    new Dictionary<string,string> { ["HoleName"] = "first", ["Length"] = "20" },
    new Dictionary<string,string> { ["HoleName"] = "second", ["Length"] = "40" },
    new Dictionary<string,string> { ["HoleName"] = "first", ["Length"] = "30" }
};
```

I want to group the above list by `HoleName` and get the max `Length`. I tried many ways, but didn't get any solution so far.

Expected output:

```cs
List<Dictionary<string,string>> data = new List<Dictionary<string,string>> 
{ 
    new Dictionary<string,string> { ["HoleName"] = "first", ["Length"] = "30" }, 
    new Dictionary<string,string> { ["HoleName"] = "second", ["Length"] = "40" }
};
```

Comment: Group into what? The list is a one-to-one mapping now.

Comment: I just want to do a group by holeName and return the list as List<Dictionary<string,string>> because I need to check validations after that

Comment: Will be great if you can provide the sample output after group by.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't look like a group, it is more like order by `HoleName`.

Comment: Hi @YongShun, the expected output is like that

List<Dictionary<string,string>> data = new List<Dictionary<string,string>> {
    new Dictionary<string,string>> { ["HoleName"]="first",["Length"]="30",},
    new Dictionary<string,string>{ ["HoleName"]="second",["Length"]="40",}}; also I want max length

Comment: Why do you have a list of directories in the first place, why not a list of objects with properties? Can't the source of the directories be converted into something that returns such a list instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can work with LINQ. Group by `HoleName` and **get the max `Length` value of the dictionary** (as the question is updated).

**Approach 1**

1. Group by `HoleName`.
2. Get the max value via `.Max()` (Must convert the `Length` to numeric type before getting the max).

```cs
using System.Linq;

List<Dictionary<string, string>> result = data.GroupBy(x => x.GetValueOrDefault("HoleName"))
    .Select(g => new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["HoleName"] = g.Key,
        ["Length"] = g.Max(x => int.Parse(x.GetValueOrDefault("Length"))).ToString()
    })
    .ToList();
```

[image]

---

**Approach 2**

1. Order by `HoleName` and followed by `Length` descending (Must convert the `Length` to numeric type).
2. Group by `HoleName`.
3. Get the first item from each group via `.First()`.

```cs
using System.Linq;

List<Dictionary<string, string>> result = data
    .OrderBy(x => x.GetValueOrDefault("HoleName")!)
    .ThenByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.GetValueOrDefault("Length")!))
    .GroupBy(x => x.GetValueOrDefault("HoleName")!)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

[image]